# Tab bar in view based application?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, uitabbar

I am new to iphone development.I have created a view based application.Now i want tab bar in that view.The first view of the tab bar is a table view and the second view is the Web-view.All the tutorials explain only tab bar based application.Since i am using view based application i finding it really hard.How to achieve it by using interface builder.please guide me.Any Sample tutorials will be more useful.Please help me out.Thanks.

Comment: Can you start it again as a "Tab-bar application"?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326814/how-to-add-tabbarcontroller-in-viewcontroller-in-iphone/

Comment: @Kristopher..I asked this question 9 days ago and pugal asked his question 7 days before.How can i duplicate it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one. This code for created a tab bar application in programmatically. So clicked the button it will open the tab bar in the view.

```
   -(IBAction) clkBtn:(id) sender
   { 

    UITabBarController *tabbar1 = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    firstViewController  *first = [[firstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"firstViewController" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *tabItem1 = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: first] autorelease];

    secondViewController  *second = [[secondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"secondViewController" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *tabItem2 = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: second] autorelease];

    tabbar1.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:tabItem1, tabItem2,nil]; 

    [self.view insertSubview:tabbar1.view belowSubview: first.view];

    [self presentModalViewController:tabbar1 animated:YES];

  }
```

Thanks,

Best of Luck.

Comment: @Warrior. Yes, because have added the navigation controller in the view. So it push the view.