# How to add tabbarcontroller in viewcontroller in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, view, uitabbarcontroller

I am new to iphone development, i have created my project in view based application and i want to add tabbar controller in my view. I have added tabbarcontroller using interface builder in my view and i cannot see the tabbar in my view.

Plz how can i add tabbarcontrolller in view.

So plz guide me.

thanks.

Comment: There's not enough information here to help you. Can you give more details? Can you show a picture of what it looks like in Interface Builder? And please show some code where you're trying to access it, but can't.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend creating another app using the "Tab Bar Application" template, and then look at the differences between that and your app.

Comment: +1 Unless you have an obscene amount of code written, it's going to be easier to just create a new project and copy your existing code. There's a lot of intricacies involved that are going to be hard to explain here.

Comment: @Kristopher.....> I have created view based application and implemented many features like RSS Feed,Map,Youtube etc. So its very hard for me to start from the beginning. Is there any other way out?.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you start over. I'm suggesting that you look at a very simple tab bar application, and figure out what you need to do to make your app match its structure.

Answer (score 1):

In your AppDelegate:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    

    // Override point for customization after app launch    
    [window addSubview:[tabBarController view]];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Where tabBarController is a outlet that's been plugged into the UITabBarController you made in 
InterfaceBuilder.