# tab bar in a view based application

Tags: iphone, sdk, view, uitabbar

I am building a view based application in xcode, and i am new to all the coding and stuff doing it now for 2 weeks. everything went great until i wanted to add a tab bar to by project.
I have searched the interwebz for this for a long time, but all that i could find was people explaining how you can add a tabbar to a window based application, Or how to build a tab bar with a tab bar application. Can someone please help me. 
And there is one more thing, i don't want to add the tabbar to the first view. I have an application with some buttons, who take you to different views, and i want to add the tabbar to the fift view, so i can not build it in the app delegate i think.

I hope this explains my problem and i sure hope someone could help me.

thanks.

Comment: I don't know if this helps you, but it might be the case, that this can't be done. I recall having read in the HIG, that the UITabbar comes with a UITabbarController and that the latter has to be the bottommost controller. I don't know if I am up-to-date though, but it would make sense, HIG-wise....

Comment: Check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310251/tab-bar-in-view-based-application

Answer (score 0):

Start with a UITabBarController.
WHen you use it in Interface builder you can add UITabBarItems (the items to select).
You can link each TabBarItem to a certain NIB. Make your NIBs for every view you want to show. Set every TabBarItem class to the correct controller of your NIB files, these will be used as the file owner of that NIB.

So:
-Make a Main NIB
-Make NIBs for every controller and make the views.
-Make the controllers and link the controllers to the NIB.
-Implement the code.

Switching UITabBarItems will make automatically change the Controllers.

Here is a tutorial for this implementation: [Tutorial](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/iphone/examples/iPhone-TabBar-Application-Tutorial-UITabBar.html)